# Are there any A.I. resources that explain the concepts and present source code?

Tags: books, resources, artificial-intelligence

Are there any A.I. resources that explain the concepts and present source code, similarly to [AI Horizon](http://www.aihorizon.com/)?

I've read books and research papers but they generally present a conceptual approach, without really delving into the source code of it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Books

- [Programming Game AI by Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556220782), by Mat Buckland.

  [Covers lots of gound](http://www.ai-junkie.com/books/toc_pgaibe.html), with good code examples on the CD for everything in the book. Notably, includes State Machines, Goal Driven Behaviour, Path Finding/Planning and Fuzzy Logic.
- [AI Techniques for Game Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556220782), by Mat Buckland.

  The book name is a bit of a misnomer. It's about [Neural Nets and Genetic Algorithms](http://www.ai-junkie.com/books/toc_aitfgp.html). The implementations are in a game format, but the information is more general. Again, all of the source is available on the CD.
- [AI Game Programming Wisdom Series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584500778), by Steve Rabin.

  The series is formatted like the Game Programming Gems series, ie. they're a collection of articles written by industry professionals and professors. The size of the articles makes them easily digestible in chunks. Some of the articles provide implementations, some are more 'high level' descriptions.
- [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136042597), by Stuart Russell and Peter Norvig.

  The [book's website](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) has the has the [source code for the algorithms](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/code.html) presented in the book, in several languages. There is also a [discussion group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/aima-talk/), where you can post questions or start a discussion about the material in the book.

#### Communities & tutorials

- [AI questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence). Most questions and answers present code, in various languages.
- [AI Horizon: Computer Science and Artificial Intelligence Programming](http://www.aihorizon.com/).
- [AIGameDev.com](http://aigamedev.com/) - It has a fair amount of recent articles with code. For some of the content, you might need to get a paid account but the insider (free) account grants access to some good articles and videos.
- The ["Miscellaneous" section of P-99](https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-problems/7) presents interesting AI problems, like Eight Queens, Sudoku, Crossword puzzle, etc, and their solutions in Prolog.
- [Chatbot tutorial](http://ai-programming.com/bot_tutorial.htm), on ai-programming.com